# 'AssemblyInfoFileMask' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, workflow-foundation-4

I am creating a custom build tfs activity to be used inside the azure continuous integration.

I have used the code from this blog:
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/06/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-10-Include-Version-Number-in-the-Build-Number.aspx

As you can see AssemblyInfoFileMask  in the code below its public.
Also please check the screenshot to see what I meant, BuildDetail its on the same class and doesnt show me the error in the blue icon.

[image]

I will paste it here the code as well:

```
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Controller)]
    public sealed class GetAssemblyVersion : CodeActivity<string>
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> AssemblyInfoFileMask { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<IBuildDetail> BuildDetail { get; set; }

        protected override string Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Obtain the runtime value of the input arguments
            string assemblyInfoFileMask = context.GetValue(this.AssemblyInfoFileMask);
            IBuildDetail buildDetail = context.GetValue(this.BuildDetail);

            var workspace = buildDetail.BuildDefinition.Workspace;
            var vc = buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            string attribute = "AssemblyFileVersion";

            // Define the regular expression to find (which is for example 'AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")' )
            Regex regex = new Regex(attribute + @"\(""\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+""\)");

            // For every workspace folder (mapping)
            foreach (var folder in workspace.Mappings)
            {
                // Get all files (recursively) that apply to the file mask
                ItemSet itemSet = vc.GetItems(folder.ServerItem + "//" + assemblyInfoFileMask, RecursionType.Full);
                foreach (Item item in itemSet.Items)
                {
                    context.TrackBuildMessage(string.Format("Download {0}", item.ServerItem));

                    // Download the file
                    string localFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                    item.DownloadFile(localFile);

                    // Read the text from the AssemblyInfo file
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(localFile);
                    // Search for the first occurrence of the version attribute
                    Match match = regex.Match(text);
                    // When found
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        // Retrieve the version number
                        string versionNumber = match.Value.Substring(attribute.Length + 2, match.Value.Length - attribute.Length - 4);
                        Version version = new Version(versionNumber);
                        // Increase the build number -> this will be the new version number for the build
                        Version newVersion = new Version(version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build + 1, version.Revision);

                        context.TrackBuildMessage(string.Format("Version found {0}", newVersion));

                        return newVersion.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return "No version found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who says it's there?  You didn't tell us what variables are in scope within the [variables and arguments of this Activity.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9IdrX.png)  Most likely the variable doesn't exist, is called something else now, or is a different type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blue Exclamation mark means you are trying to pass the value of a `Variable`/`Argument` called `AssemblyInfoFileMask` to a `Property` on your Activity called `AssemblyInfoFileMask`.

You need to declare an Argument or Variable yourself to pass to your activity.

If you want to be able to set the `AssemblyInfoFileMask` in your build definitions, then you need to declare it as an Argument.

See this updated version of your image you will see where you declare it:

[image: Arguments]

Once you have declared an Argument, you need to find the `MetaData` Collection Argument and add it there too. See [this post](http://ericphan.net/blog/2011/5/31/adding-configurable-parameters-to-a-custom-tfs-2010-build-te.html) for more details.

If you don't need to set it in a build definition (it's going to be constant for all builds), then just add a `Variable` and set it's value to the Pattern you require.

Comment: looks like that tutorial is not well explained then :(

Comment: maybe you can check this question as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031434/the-path-fullstacksampleapplication-is-not-a-file-type-invalidoperationexcep